# IsInArray function error: Type Mismatch VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this, it gives me an error saying

> ByRef argument type mismatch

in the if statement.

I had all of the arrays declared as variants, but that also gave me an error when I tried to run the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sub sort()

Dim rowNo As Integer
Dim colNo As Integer
Dim PIList(6) As Long
Dim GSList(2) As Long
Dim FilterList(91) As Long
Dim currCellCont As Long

rowNo = 2
colNo = 2
PIList(6) = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5)
GSList(2) = Array(6,7)
FilterList(91) = Array(89752, 89753, 89754, 89755, 89756, 89757, 89758, 89759, 89760, 89761, 89762, 89763, 89764, 89765, 89766, 89767, 89768, 89769, 89770, 89771, 89772, 89773, 89774, 89775, 89776, 89777, 89778, 89779, 89780, 89781, 89782, 89783, 89784, 89785, 89786, 89787, 89788, 89789, 89790, 89791, 89792, 89793, 89794, 89795, 89796, 89797, 89798, 89799, 89800, 89801, 89802, 89803, 89804, 89805, 89806, 89807, 89808, 89809, 89810, 89811, 89812, 89813, 89814, 89815, 89816, 89817, 89818, 89819, 89820, 89821, 89822, 89823, 89824, 89825, 89826, 89827, 89828, 89829, 89830, 89831, 89832, 89833, 89834, 89835, 89836, 89837, 89838, 89839, 89840, 89841, 89842)
currCellCont = Cells(rowNo, colNo).Value

Do Until IsEmpty(currCellCont)
    If IsInArray(currCellCont, PIList) Then
        Cells(rowNo, 9).Value = "PI"
    ElseIf IsInArray(currCellCont, GSList) Then
        Cells(rowNo, 9).Value = "GS"
    ElseIf IsInArray(currCellCont, FilterList) Then
        Cells(roNo, colNo).Value = "Filter"
    End If
    currCellCont = Cells(rowNo + 1, colNo)
Loop

End Sub


Function IsInArray(lookingFor As Long, arr As Long) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(lookingFor, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: There's no array parameter in IsInArray

Comment: That code has more problems than just the missing `()` on `arr`.  `PIList(6) = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5)` is trying to assign a `Variant` array to the 6th position (7th position if it is zero-based) of a `Long` array - which will give a "Type mismatch" error.

Answer (score 2):

Use variant arrays:

```
Sub sort()

Dim rowNo As Integer
Dim colNo As Integer
Dim PIList() As Variant
Dim GSList() As Variant
Dim FilterList() As Variant
Dim currCellCont As Long

rowNo = 2
colNo = 2
PIList = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GSList = Array(6, 7)
FilterList = Array(89752, 89753, 89754, 89755, 89756, 89757, 89758, 89759, 89760, 89761, 89762, 89763, 89764, 89765, 89766, 89767, 89768, 89769, 89770, 89771, 89772, 89773, 89774, 89775, 89776, 89777, 89778, 89779, 89780, 89781, 89782, 89783, 89784, 89785, 89786, 89787, 89788, 89789, 89790, 89791, 89792, 89793, 89794, 89795, 89796, 89797, 89798, 89799, 89800, 89801, 89802, 89803, 89804, 89805, 89806, 89807, 89808, 89809, 89810, 89811, 89812, 89813, 89814, 89815, 89816, 89817, 89818, 89819, 89820, 89821, 89822, 89823, 89824, 89825, 89826, 89827, 89828, 89829, 89830, 89831, 89832, 89833, 89834, 89835, 89836, 89837, 89838, 89839, 89840, 89841, 89842)
currCellCont = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNo, colNo).Value
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet if always the same or ActiveSheet if on various sheets.
    Do Until currCellCont = 0
        If IsInArray(currCellCont, PIList) Then
            .Cells(rowNo, 9).Value = "PI"
        ElseIf IsInArray(currCellCont, GSList) Then
            .Cells(rowNo, 9).Value = "GS"
        ElseIf IsInArray(currCellCont, FilterList) Then
            .Cells(roNo, colNo).Value = "Filter"
        End If
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
        currCellCont = .Cells(rowNo, colNo).Value
    Loop
End With


End Sub


Function IsInArray(lookingFor As Long, arr() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(lookingFor, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: I guess, he's an expert on ActiveSheet theme) BTW, you didn't answer, why prefixing sheet is not enough...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by prefixing sheets.

Comment: I mean, why prefixing with just "ActiveSheet" is not enough?

Comment: You mean by leaving it blank and letting vbe assume the activesheet?  Mat's Mug did answer that in his comment to you on the last string.  Normally in this situation I would use `With ActiveSheet` or if the sheet was specific I would use `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` then I did not need to manually activate the sheet and could run the code from anywhere. Then just prefix the ranges with `.`. But in this specific case it was just me being lazy and using copy/paste to get the minimum amount of stability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160821/discussion-between-johnyl-and-scott-craner).